# Maximum factorial that is formed by three digits?

Tags: math, logic

Number of digits that are present in the maximum number that is formed using three digits?
Maximum factorial that is formed by three digits?

This was a question asked on a site.
I am not able to understand is there any thing tricky i am not getting?

i have tried 3 and 720 but it is incorrect

Comment: Maybe it means "using as many instances of the operators * / - + ^ as you want, but only using three digits, form a mathematical expression with the largest possible value. How many digits does it have?" Ex. (9^9)^9 is much larger than three digits. Where did you get this question? What was its exact wording?

Comment: "First line of output is number of digits that are present in the maximum number that is formed using three digits
Second line of output is the maximum factorial that is formed by three digits"

Comment: This doesn't sound like a very well-thought-out coding challenge site. Struggling with poorly worded exercises won't make you a better programmer. I suggest just trying somewhere else.

Comment: Wow, these are incredibly ambiguous questions. Do you have a source ?

Comment: No I don't have the source

Comment: This is the Source:http://www.codechef.com/GRCO2015/problems/NUMMAX3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum factorial which can be formed using 3 digits is 999!.
The answer can be easily obtained from wolfram alpha.
[Number of digits](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=number%20of%20digits%20in%20%28999%21%29) in 999!.

999!=[Answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=999%21)